# How to Configure shiro.ini for custom realm in spring-boot app?

Tags: java, apache, spring-boot, shiro

I have my Custom realm

```
public class MyCustomRealm extends JdbcRealm  {
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) {
        // Custom code
    }
}
```

shiro.ini file as follows:

```
jdbcRealm= com.company.security.shiro.realm.MyCustomRealm 
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
ds = com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
ds.serverName = jdbc:mysql://datasource
ds.user = user
ds.password = pass
jdbcRealm.dataSource=$ds
securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm
```

Anybody aware what need to do to configure/register shiro.ini for spring-boot project? or what configuration required in SpringBootApp.java file?

```
@Bean
public Realm realm() {
    Realm realm  = new IniRealm("classpath:shiro.ini");
    DefaultSecurityManager securityManager = new DefaultSecurityManager(realm);
    SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
    return realm;
}
```

Using above bean getting following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shiroEventBusAwareBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/apache/shiro/spring/boot/autoconfigure/ShiroBeanAutoConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor' defined in class path resource [org/apache/shiro/spring/boot/autoconfigure/ShiroAnnotationProcessorAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityManager' defined in class path resource [org/apache/shiro/spring/config/web/autoconfigure/ShiroWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'securityManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'iniClasspathRealm' defined in class path resource [org/apache/shiro/spring/boot/autoconfigure/ShiroAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Error initializing bean [iniClasspathRealm]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ini instance and/or resourcePath resulted in null or empty Ini configuration.  Cannot load account data.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ini instance and/or resourcePath resulted in null or empty Ini configuration.  Cannot load account data.
    at org.apache.shiro.realm.text.IniRealm.onInit(IniRealm.java:165) ~[shiro-core-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
    at org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthenticatingRealm.init(AuthenticatingRealm.java:398) ~[shiro-core-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
    at org.apache.shiro.spring.LifecycleBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(LifecycleBeanPostProcessor.java:89) ~[shiro-spring-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
```

Comment: My guess is your shiro.ini file is NOT being found on your classpath

Comment: Thank you Brian, I have shiro.ini file in path src/main/resources

Comment: Is it making it to your classpath? Can you stick a breakpoint on `org.apache.shiro.realm.text.IniRealm.onInit(IniRealm.java:165)` and poke around your cp?

Comment: Hi Brian sorry for late response. To your suggestion to debug in IniRealm, I totally removed ini file from my classpath as I am using spring boot so taking advantage of Bean to configure realm. I observed if we really dont need ini file then better to delete from classpath than just commenting out the ini cofiguration. In this case having commented configuration in ini file throws exception Ini instance and/or resourcePath resulted in null or empty Ini configuration.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is how I made it work, Please suggest if any other better way of doing it.

-Removed existing Bean realm().
-Added authorizer bean to SprinBootApp main class

    @Bean
        public Authorizer authorizer() {
            MyCusotmRealm realm = new MyCusotmRealm();
            return realm;
        }

- Added shiro filter chain definition(seems crucial).  


     @Bean
       public ShiroFilterChainDefinition shiroFilterChainDefinition() {
       DefaultShiroFilterChainDefinition chainDefinition = new 
                DefaultShiroFilterChainDefinition();
                chainDefinition.addPathDefinition("/**", "anon");
                return chainDefinition;
            }

 - Removed datasource ds from shiro.ini, as I am leveraging database connection through spring boot application.properties file.
   shiro.ini will look like:    

   jdbcRealm= com.company.security.shiro.realm.MyCustomRealm 
   securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm
```